# How to set Longitude And Latitude to picture using xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new in Xamarin Forms and I got a task. I want to create one camera application which takes photos with details of longitude and latitude. I have created a camera app, but I am stuck on one question: how do I set longitude and latitude properties of taken pic?

Here is my code to take a photo, now I have to set details longitude and latitude:

```
private MediaFile _mediaFile;

private async void TakePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "myImage.jpg",
                SaveToAlbum = true
            });

            if (_mediaFile == null)
                return;

            LocalPathLabel.Text = _mediaFile.Path;

            FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return _mediaFile.GetStream();
            });
        }
```

Can you please help me with my task?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link for saving properties of Image for Android. Same way there has to be something for iOS.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73547/how-to-add-properties-location-to-image

Comment: Thanks for the response but i already refer the same code, but its not working, can you please share me some other code, with reference above, I mean after taking pic, which steps should be done?

Comment: I am getting error after installing package ExifInterface, do you have any other options?

Comment: "getting error" is not a useful description of the problem.  Please be specific about the exact error message and what code is causing it.